# XmlSerializer strange thing

Tags: c#, .net

sorry for my English.
I have the strange thing with XmlSerializer. This is my code

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Radio
{
    public bool hasSubWoofers;
    public double[] stationPresets;

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public string radioId = "X-3454";
}

[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public Radio radio = new Radio();
    public int speed;
}

[Serializable]
public class JamesBondCar : Car
{
    public bool canFly;
    public bool canSubmerge;

    private string flag = "string flag";
}
```

class JamesBondCar has the private member 'flag' and during serialization XmlSerializer shouldn't serialize it. In XML I'm looking it. The is NO 'flag' field:

```
<JamesBondCar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <radio>
    <hasSubWoofers>true</hasSubWoofers>
    <stationPresets>
      <double>192.3</double>
      <double>45.2</double>
      <double>456.3</double>
    </stationPresets>
  </radio>
  <speed>342</speed>
  <canFly>true</canFly>
  <canSubmerge>false</canSubmerge>
</JamesBondCar>
```

but, this is main function:

```cs
            JamesBondCar bond = new JamesBondCar();
            bond.canFly = true;
            bond.canSubmerge = false;
            bond.speed = 342;
            bond.radio.hasSubWoofers = true;
            bond.radio.stationPresets = new double[] { 192.3, 45.2, 456.3 };
            bond.radio.radioId = "Y-3424";

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("car.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JamesBondCar));
            serializer.Serialize(fs, bond);
            fs.Close();

            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("car.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            JamesBondCar jcar = (JamesBondCar)serializer.Deserialize(fs2);
```

after serialization in debugging I can se in the jcar instanse 'flag' field, that has "string flag" value. How is it possible?  XML hasn't got this value.

Comment: Do you mean after DEserialization?

Comment: yes, after deserialization, sorry

Comment: You don't need `[Serializable]` here, btw

Comment: thanks, i didn't know it. These attributes remained after BinarySerializer analysis and i've thought that they are required for xml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any private member fields that have default values like this will be initialized with these default values when the object is constructed (i.e. when the object constructor is called).

Comment: thanks, I cant vote up you because I havan't 15 reputation point)

Comment: @Wachburn, don't worry, I did it for ya ;)

Answer (score 2):

Different serializers have different rules; `XmlSerializer` happens to be one that initializes the object by demanding and using a public parameterless constructor (commonly the "default" constructor added by the C# compiler). This also has the effect of running all the *field initializers* (such as `private string flag = "string flag";`), which are (at the IL level) part of the constructor.

By contrast, something like `DataContractSerializer` ***doesn't*** run the constructor; it doesn't run *any* constructor (there are hooks to do this... it isn't very interesting). This means it relies on the serialized data (and any serialization callbacks - note that `XmlSerializer` doesn't *support* serialization callbacks).

Other serializers may allow you to *choose* which approach to take.

If you want to skip the constructor and work with non-public data, then `DataContractSerializer` can do that, but offers much less control over the xml. If you use `XmlSerializer` you need to follow the rules it defines.